# Shelf_router error : Closure call with mismatched arguments

Tags: shelf-router

I am using Dart server and using Shelf_router.
The route is configured as follows.
The payroll api is mounted as follows:

```
app.mount('/payroll/', PayrollApi(db).router);
```

The PayrollApi has the following:

```
router.get('/employer/<erId>/frequency/<frequency>', erPayrollApi2);
```

The erPayrollApi2 functions is as follows:

```
 Future erPayrollApi2(shelf.Request req) async {
var erId = req.params['erId'];
var frequency = req.params['frequency'];

print(erId);
print(frequency);

shelf.Response.ok('Got message: f: $frequency, erId: $erId');
```

}

Sending the following URL using Postman:

```
https://localhost:843/apyroll/employer/<er100>/frequency/<Weekly>
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred. X
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: 
function  *PayrollApi.erPayrollApi2
Receiver: Closure: (Request) => Future<dynamic> from Function
```

*erPayrollApi2":
Tried calling: PayrollApi.erPayrollApiZ(Instance of "Request" "%3Cer100%3E"
"%3CWeekly%3E")
Found: PayrollApi.erPayrollApiZ(Request) => Future)

I am seeing the parameters 'er100' and 'Weekly' but stops shot of calling my function erPayrolApi2.

[image: Shelf_error_image]

Comment: Had to change method signature to: 
Future pay(shelf.Request req, String erId, String frequency) async {
 and add return Shelf.Response.ok

Answer (score 0):

Changes written in comments above fixed the problem